# Python outputting entire text file as opposed to line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-3.6

I am trying to output data from a text file line by line to a search box on a website. I am using Selenium to interact with the web page.

However when my code writes into the text field on the web page it pastes the entire contents of the text file rather than the first line, load the page, then search for the second line, and so on and so fourth..... see below my code:

```
with open("SerialNumbers.txt") as sn:
    for line in sn:
        search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('criteria[1][1]')
        search_field.click()
        serials = sn.read().splitlines()
        search_field.send_keys(serials)
        search_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

When sending the first line of my text file (serials) to the search_field it starts writing the entire contents of SerialNumbers.txt

Please advise where i am going wrong if possible as i am certain that defining my variable as sn.read().splitlines() should tell python to read line by line from a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, **you're already iterating through the lines of the file** because of `for line in sn:`. However, **`serials = sn.read().splitlines()` causes `serials` to contain a list of the lines in your file**. Since `send_keys` can take a list of keys to send, **it just sends all the data in the file**. If you want to search one line, then the next, etc., then **I recommend just putting `line` in your first `send_keys`** like so:

```
with open("SerialNumbers.txt") as sn:
    for line in sn:
        search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('criteria[1][1]')
        search_field.click()
        search_field.send_keys(line)
        search_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You may need to trim line endings, as each line will likely contain the `\n` character. You can do this with `str.rstrip()` which will remove all trailing whitespace characters if that wouldn't break your searching.

**Alternatively, you can do `sn.read().splitlines()` and iterate over those like so:**

```
with open("SerialNumbers.txt") as sn:
    serials = sn.read().splitlines()
    for serial in serials:
        search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('criteria[1][1]')
        search_field.click()
        search_field.send_keys(serial)
        search_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your file reading like this:

```
with open(r'c:\Users\xf01145\Downloads\scores.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line, end='')
```